# How can I create templates for file extensions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my Vue.js projects **almost all the times** I need this code snippet as a template.

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
<template>

<script>

export default{
    data(){
        return{
        }
    },
    methods:{
    },
    created(){
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code each and every time I create a file with the extension **.vue** to automatically add that snippet to the file?

Simply, when I create new file with a certain extension, the predefined template for that extension should automatically be added to the file.

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614398/vscode-triggering-a-snippet-upon-file-creation/58460632#58460632 it was designed to work on file creation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There isn't, not natively. But there is an extension called [File Templates for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bam.vscode-file-templates) that allows you to create your own file templates and generate from them. But I think you'd benefit from making an extension to do just that and maybe even more.

In the meantime, you can use a snippet to generate this instead of having to copy paste.

Go to **File > Preferences > User Snippets** and choose **Vue** from the dropdown. Vue will only show up if you have installed an extension that supports this file type. In this case, I'd recommend [Vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur), but you probably have it already.

Then just add this entry to your `vue.json` file:

```
"vuetpl" : {
        "body": [
            "<template>",
            "\t<div>",
            "\t\t$0",
            "\t</div>",
            "</template>",

            "<script>",

            "export default{",
            "\tdata(){",
                "\t\treturn{",
                    "\t\t\t",
                "\t\t}",
            "\t},",
            "\tmethods:{",
                "\t\t",
            "\t},",
            "\tcreated(){",
                "\t\t",
            "\t}",
            "}",
            "</script>",

            "<style scoped>",
            "</style>",
        ],
        "prefix": "vuetpl",
        "description": "Creates a new template."
    }
```

Then, when you create a new `.vue` file, just type `vuetpl` and press `tab` to autocomplete, and you'll have this:

[image: Template]

Of course, you can also use a [Snippet Generator](https://snippet-generator.app/) to make your own snippets.

Comment: I have written a replacement of the Template extension by Venkatesh Boddu, it is [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Answer (score 16):

This is in Stable v1.70.

##### 1.  Make sure you haven't disabled this setting by setting it to `hidden`:

```
// Controls if the untitled text hint should be visible in the editor.  
"workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "text",   // "text" is the default
```

##### 2.  Make some snippets that will serve as templates for whatever languages you are interested in in a snippets file (here they are in a global snippets file):

```
"vue template": {

    "isFileTemplate": true,  // this is the key

    "scope": "vue",

    "prefix": "vueTemplate",
    "body": [
        "const a = 'vue template'"
    ],
    "description": "vue template"
},

"javascript template": {
    "isFileTemplate": true,
    "scope": "javascript",

    "prefix": "jsTemplate",
    "body": [
        "const a = 'javascript template'"
    ],
    "description": "javascript template"
},
```

The `isFileTemplate` option is key here.  Any snippet with this option will appear in the following workflows.

If you have the `"scope": "someLangID here"` set in the keybinding then vscode can and will automatically change the current editor's language to that language ID.

##### 3.  Create a new file:

###### a.  with the command `File: New Untitled File` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Then you will see the message at the top of the file as in this demo:

```
....   or fill with template, or   .....
```

Clicking on that will show any snippets with that `"isFileTemplate": true,` set.  Choosing one from the resulting QuickPick thaht opens up will input the snippet contents AND change the editor's language association to the `scope` value.

[image: new file template from a snippet]

As you can see from the demo I frequently have to toggle focus to another file and back to the new one to get the prompt text to appear for some reason.

###### b.  You can also modify an existing file to the snippet content and language by using the command (found in the Command Palette)

```
Snippets: Fill File With Snippet
```

[This command `Snippets: Fill File with Snippet : workbench.action.populateFileFromSnippet` does not have a default keybinding.]

As you can see in the demo, using this command will delete all the current contents of the file AND change the language association of that editor.  But will not change the file extension (as from `.ts` to `.js` for example if you have previously saved and named a file0.

[image: existing file template from snippet demo]

---

So making your initial snippets will probably be the hardest part, you might look into the [snippet generator app](https://snippet-generator.app/).

Here is the sample template I used in the demos above:

```json
"ts/js template": {
    "isFileTemplate": true,
    "scope": "typescript",
    "prefix": "tsTemplate",   
    "body": [
        "import * as vscode from 'vscode';",
        "import { EXTENSION_NAME, DecoratorSettings, getSettings } from \"./config\";",
        "import * as colors from './colors';",
        "import { FileDecorator } from './decorator';",
        "import * as utilities from './utilities';",
        "",         // blank line
        "import * as fs from 'fs';",
    ],
    "description": "ts template"
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but it was not obvious from a quick google search. Are templates now included in vscode ?

Comment: @userrandrand Yes, after a fashion.  As the steps above demonstrate you can create a special snippet which you can choose in a newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good plugin called "[Snippet Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wware.snippet-creator)" that makes creating snippets painless.

I wanted a quick "template" file that I could re-use. Copied the text, then used command "Create Snippet", and it was done in a couple of steps.

It could also be used to create the same Vue templates mentioned above. You can edit the snippet, insert your tab stops etc, just visit **Code > Preferences > Configure User Snippets** once created

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has already been answered I'm not going to cover snippets as a solution. Rather, I want to provide an option for those, like myself, who are not keen on using a third party website/extension to generate these snippets. Below is a fairly trivial Powershell function that will create snippets from scripblocks or strings (assuming you use another language). It would not be hard to convert this to your language of choice.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Creates a VSCode snippet from a given string or scriptblock
.EXAMPLE
    $Snippet = New-VSCodeSnippet `
        -Name "Print to console" `
        -Description "Log output to console" `
        -Prefix "log" `
        -IsFileTemplate `
        -Body {
Write-Host '$1'
'$2'
$foo = 'foo'
Write-Host $foo
}
    $Snippet                  # Display snippet
    $Snippet | Set-Clipboard  # Copy snippet to paste
#>
function New-VSCodeSnippet {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Description,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]       
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Prefix,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory,HelpMessage="Script body. Should normally be a string or scriptblock but can be anything that converts to a string object.")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Object] $Body,

        [Parameter(HelpMessage="File which this snippet is relevant to. (eg powershell)")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $Scope,

        [switch] $IsFileTemplate
    )

    # VSCode snippets treats numeric ($1, $2, etc) special so escape words
    # starting with $ (variables) and an alphabetic char, followed by any
    # non-whitespace char.
    $BodyLines = [Regex]::Replace($Body.ToString(), '(\B[$][a-zA-Z]\w+)', '\$1').Trim() -split "`n"

    $Properties = @{
        description = $Description
        prefix = $prefix
        isFileTemplate = $IsFileTemplate.IsPresent
        body = $BodyLines
    }
    if ($Scope) { $Properties.scope = $Scope }

    # Need a wrapper around $Properties to use ConvertTo-Json
    $Snippet = ([PSCustomObject] @{ $Name = $Properties }) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    # Remove braces and empty lines
    return $Snippet.Trim('{}').Trim()
}
```

This is the result of the example in the function header. The indentation isn't quite as nice as this in PSv5 but VSCode reformats it when you paste it into the editor.

```json
    "Print to console":  {
        "prefix":  "log",
        "body":  [
                     "Write-Host \u0027$1\u0027\r",
                     "\u0027$2\u0027\r",
                     "\\$foo = \u0027foo\u0027\r",
                     "Write-Host \\$foo"
                 ],
        "description":  "Log output to console",
        "isFileTemplate":  true
    }
```