# VsCode - Triggering a snippet upon file creation

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I wanted to know if it is possible to trigger a user defined custom snippet when I create a file in vscode.

I started learning Golang recently and noticed that there is some boilerplate code that goes into creating the `main.go` file.

So I created my custom snippet for it and now now I can trigger the snippet manually and save me some keystrokes of typing.

I wanted to go one step further, so that whenever I create a new file named `main.go` from within VsCode, it should automatically fire that snippet and insert the biolerplate code for me, without me having to manually trigger the snippet.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: How are you creating the new file?  That would be helpful info as there is more than one way to do so.

Comment: I am creating the file from within the vscode using the menu options in explorer.

Comment: You could easily do this by writing a simple VSCode extension.

Comment: Only if I knew how to write a _"simple"_ extension, I wouldn't have asked on SO.!!

Answer (score 8):

Check out this extension: [Auto Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.auto-snippet):

With this in your settings.json:

```
"autoSnippet.snippets": [
  { "pattern": "**/main.go", "snippet": "main-go-template" },
],
```

[Note that the example settings in the extension docs has a few syntax errors - use my example above - I have filed an issue with the creator.]

And then your snippet

```
"main-go-template": {
  "prefix": "zz",
  "body": [
    ...  // you can use tabstops and transforms just like regular snippets
  ]
  "description": "javascript template"
}
```

Then creating a new `main.go` file or opening an empty one should trigger the snippet.

It is a good idea to reload vscode whenever you make a change to this extension's settings.

Here is a demo of a gulpfile with common boilerplate:

[image: demo of auto snippet extension]

---

Also see this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bam.vscode-file-templates