# Boilerplate In VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to know if it is possible to create a custom boilerplate in Visual Studio Code for any file type. I code in C++ all the time and I usually spend five minutes setting up the same thing. I have a boilerplate file that I now just copy code off of, but is it possible to set up VSCode so that it automatically sets up the code whenever I create a new cpp file?

Comment: How about Snippets?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS code how to create templates for file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/vs-code-how-to-create-templates-for-file-extensions)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614398/vscode-triggering-a-snippet-upon-file-creation/58460632#58460632 Triggering a snippet upon file creation.