# can I add custom default code in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I create a default code on VSC, that whenever I open a new page to write a code my default code(my written code) is there already?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that but you should look into snippets: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: What do mean with "page"? There are no "pages" in vscode? Do you mean files? What should be inside the files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create templates for file extensions in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/how-can-i-create-templates-for-file-extensions-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the extension: [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

You can specify global or project templates, based on name and extension.