# vscode auto insert <?php when creating a php file

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets

I want vs code to automatically add `<?php` when creating a new php file
Is there any Extension or code snippets that I can add in the `snippet.code-snippets.json` file?
I searched on the internet but there is no such solution
Please Help

Comment: Not same requirement but you can take an idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/how-can-i-create-templates-for-file-extensions-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: thank you so much @OMiShah I found what I was looking for!

Comment: you could use extension: [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same issue
just use this extension [Auto Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.auto-snippet)