# How to get file name when overriding VS Code snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to override the `rfce` snippet in VS code but I can't seem to be able to get the filename autofilled when there's a named file. Where the file is not saved(unnamed) it should just be `NameOfComponent` but if the file is saved(has a name), the snippet should name the component the same as the file name but without the extension. Here's what I have so far:

```
"React Component": {
  "prefix": "rfce",
  "body": [
    "import React, { useState, useEffect } from \"react\";",
    "",
    "const ${1:NameOfComponent} = () => {",
    "  return (",
    "    <>",
    "       ${2:<div>Hello World</div>}",
    "    </>",
    "  );",
    "};",
    "",
    "export default ${1:NameOfComponent};"
  ],
  "description": "React Component"
}
```

Comment: what is the use of a file you will not save, eventually it will have a filename, so save the file and then call the snippet

Comment: there is a long and descriptive page about snippets in the VSC docs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to make your snippet into a template for new files see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043147/836330.  Snippet template functionality is being built in to vscode.

---

Presumably you have found `$TM_FILENAME_BASE` from [vscode snippet variables documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) as the variable you need to get the file name of the current file without its extension.

**Ideally** what you would like to do is a `choice` element (see [Choice doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice) and something like this:

`"const ${1|NameOfComponent},$TM_FILENAME_BASE|}...",`  // does not work

That won't work because according to the snippet grammar `choice` options can only be `text`:

`choice      ::= '${' int '|' text (',' text)* '|}'`

So you would have to simulate a `choice` as close as possible.  The following snippet does that in two ways:

```
"React Component": {
  "prefix": "rfce",
  "body": [
    "import React, { useState, useEffect } from \"react\";",
    "",

    // "const ${1:NameOfComponent}${2:$TM_FILENAME_BASE} = () => {",      // option 1 works

    "const ${1:${2:NameOfComponent}${3:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}} = () => {",  // option 2 works
    
    "  return (",
    "    <>",
    "       ${4:<div>Hello World</div>}",
    "    </>",
    "  );",
    "};",
    "",
    "export default $1;"  // uses option 2
  ],
  "description": "React Component"
}
```

Option 1 simply lists both `${1:NameOfComponent}${2:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}` presents both "options" - each will be selected in turn, just delete the one you don't want when it is selected and <kbd>tab</kbd> to go on.  This is pretty straightforward but does require you to use the whole construction `${1:NameOfComponent}${2:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}` every time you want that value.

Option 2 wraps the whole thing in another tabstop:

`${1:${2:NameOfComponent}${3:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}}}` which is a little trickier but then the result is put into tabstop `$1` and then that is all you need to refer to when you want the result (as in the last line of the snippet).

You just have to practice a little - there is an extra <kbd>tab</kbd> at the start to select `NameOfComponent`.  To accept it just <kbd>tab</kbd> past it to select the fileName and delete that, or vice versa - delete `NameOfComponent` when it is selected and <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the fileName - if you want it just <kbd>tab</kbd> to go on to the next tabstop.

The result of that inital tabstop will be put into `$1` which can then be used elsewhere without the need to go through the option selection stuff again.

Here is a demo using option 2:

[image: choice snippet demo]

Comment: Good tip!  One small issue:  I think you have an extra `}` at the end of the `{$1 ... }` line (notice the generated snippet shows that extra `}` as well).

Comment: @JasonFrank Thanks, I updated the code - might be awhile before I update the gif though...

Answer (score 8):

You can use [TM_FILENAME_BASE - The filename of the current document without its extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice)

Example for a react functional typed component:

```
  "create react functional component": {
"prefix": "trafce",
"body": [
  "import { FC } from \"react\"",
  "\n",
  "interface Props {\n\n}",
  "\n",
  "const $TM_FILENAME_BASE:FC<Props> = ({}) => {",
  "   return (",
  "       <div> ${1:$TM_FILENAME_BASE} </div>",
  "   )",
  "}",
  "\n",
  "export default $TM_FILENAME_BASE"
],
"description": "Create a react-typed functional component "
}
```

See the demo
[Demo for the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtc7g.gif)