# How can I open a new Visual Studio Code file with pre-set template code inside it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, config

I would like to know if it is possible to open a new file in Visual Studio Code with code already written inside it, like a template code.

This is to save time instead of writing the same line of code on every new file I create for a project.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML Boilerplate template code ? If Yes then I have a solution I have created a npm script `tweety-create` just run once it will automatically create basic HTML/CSS/JS template with all css reset code and file link  => https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweety-create

Comment: Thank you but what I mean is automatically having the line /// <reference types="cypress" /> at the top of all of my files when I just click the 'new file' icon on VSCode.

Comment: have a look at extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Comment: Thank you will check it out now.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043147/836330 Snippet file templates are being built-in to vscode.  Insertion is not automatic on file creation but it will be pretty easy to create and populate files.

Answer (score 2):

I found that what I was asking for was essentially how to create a code snippet that holds a template code. In Visual Studio Code:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) and search preferences:Configure User Snippits
2. Then search javascript.json
3. Then write in your code (if you don't know the format use: https://snippet-generator.app/ or search how to write it)
4. Then add that code and use your assigned prefix keyword to generate the template on your file.