# Is there a way for a user to make a file that has boilerplate or precoded code?

Tags: python, code-generation, vscode-extensions, code-snippets, boilerplate

I am trying to make an extension that has the ability to, by GUI or by command, create a python file that has code in it upon creation. I know you can make snippet that allows you to type in a command and then the snippet will paste or generate in the empty file. But what I would really like is just the ability to create a python file and have the code already there, **upon file creation.**

Ideally, I would like to make some kind of change to the file menu of VS code so that there's a button/panel that reads "start new XYZ process" and when the user clicks it, a python file is created with code already generated for them. However, I have found this to be extremely difficult to figure out. If you know how this could be done please let me know, but just helping with the goals of the first paragraph is good too. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know 1) how to write functions in python and 2) how to write lines to newly created files?

Comment: I think you are not asking how to write *Python code* which does that, are you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create templates for file extensions in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/how-can-i-create-templates-for-file-extensions-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for exactly, but check out python skeleton - will create a whole project for you, and supports plugins for specific project types :: [ https://pypi.org/project/skeleton/ ]

Comment: Thank you guys. the File extension from mkrieger1s answer works best for my purposes. Ill need to figure out how to code in some pre-made templates. so users of the extension I make dont already need the file in question to make a template for it.