# VSCode: is it possible to create a command that will fill a file with text on creation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

At my place of work, we have a standard source header. I've been using snippets to generate it when adding text to a file. However, since it's supposed to be pretty much used on everything, I figure I might as well see if I can automate its generation on file creation.

Is there a way to automatically add text to a file on creation in `vscode`? Can I generate different text based on the file extension?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571335/954986

Comment: you can try an updated version of [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)