# How to use template when creating new python file on VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my python file I always start with the following lines

```py
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl
sys.append('C:\\MyPackages')

rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'font.size': 20,
    'text.latex.preamble': r"\usepackage{bm}",
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
```

Is there a way to indicate to VScode that each time I create a new `file.py`, it will start with the previous lines ?

For now, I copy/paste a 'template.py' but this is not really convenient.

And because I work with Windows, I also tried to add 'C:\MyPackages' to the user variables Path but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043147/9938317

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Doing this kind of repetitive task we can use **snippets** in VSCode.

Step 1 : Hit > <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> open command palette.

Step 2 : Select **Snippets: Configure User Snippets**

Step 3 : Select **Python**

Step 4 : paste below code in **python.json** file. change prefix value. like "prefix": "hedwin" so now when you type **hedwin** vscode will paste our code snippet

```json
"": {
  "prefix": "",
  "body": [
    "import sys",
    "import matplotlib as mpl",
    "sys.append('C:\\\\MyPackages')",
    "",
    "rc_fonts = {",
    "    \"text.usetex\": True,",
    "    'font.size': 20,",
    "    'text.latex.preamble': r\"\\usepackage{bm}\",",
    "}",
    "mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)"
  ],
  "description": ""
}
```

For making snippet : [snippet generator](https://snippet-generator.app/?description=&tabtrigger=&snippet=import+sys%0Aimport+matplotlib+as+mpl%0Asys.append%28%27C%3A%5C%5CMyPackages%27%29%0A%0Arc_fonts+%3D+%7B%0A++++%22text.usetex%22%3A+True%2C%0A++++%27font.size%27%3A+20%2C%0A++++%27text.latex.preamble%27%3A+r%22%5Cusepackage%7Bbm%7D%22%2C%0A%7D%0Ampl.rcParams.update%28rc_fonts%29&mode=vscode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates).

Save a file `python.py` with your start content in the default template location. (see extension page, you have to set it in the settings)

Then use `Ctrl+N` and select `Python`, give it a name and the file is created.

You can add variables and snippets to customize the instantiation.